# Using Bit compression

Tags: compression, bit

Lately I've been thinking about compression on computers, and stumbled upon the question, 'why isn't bitwise compression more common for large files?'.
I tried looking around and didn't manage to find anyone talking about the subject, at least the way I meant it, , I might not be talking about the same subject, or not using the correct name so I'll explain what I had in mind.
Lets say we have th following string `"Hi I'm a string!"`.
Its value in binary is:

> 01001000011010010010000001001001001001110110110100100000011000010010000001110011011101000111001001101001011011100110011100100001

As you can see in the binary sequence there are more then several reoccurring sequences of 0's and 1's. My idea is to remove them, and include an indexing file, saying exactly where you need to add 0's or 1's and how many, for example let's break it to the first three bytes:

> 01001000 01101001 00100000

The indexing file will look like this:
[2,1] [5,3]
[1,1] [5, 1]
[0,1] [3, 4]
And the binary will be:
`01010 010101 010`
And of course since there will be filler bits until it reaches an 
 `N%8 == 0`
My question is why isn't this type of compression common\existant, if it is I would love to see an example of it being used practically in the real world, if it doesn't I would love to learn why it isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm would work on certain types of data. Is is far less effective than other algorithms that are in use, though.

For example, the LZ facility of algorithms can reference data that has been seen before. It can reference strings of zeroes like your algorithm but it can also reference any other pattern. It is more general.

I don't think your algorithm would achieve compression with common English text. There are too many 1 bits and storing a bit position takes many bits.